# What should be done for questions where the person asking questions never comes back?

Tags: discussion, support

Though it is true that Stack Overflow is like a 'DoingGoodDeed without thanks' kind of a platform, what should be done when the person who asked questions never returns?

It's like they did not verify the answer or they didn't care. The people who answer spend quite some time on verifying the code, resolving issues, etc. Should they be reminded to check it?

Comment: Provided its a good question we don't care if the person asking it responds or not, so nothing needs to be done.

Comment: If only the original asker can verify answers, then the Q&A is not particularly *useful* to anyone else, is it?

Comment: Usually such reminders are covert requests to upvote or accept the answer. There are people who routinely post such comments, creating nothing but noise. I think many askers just happily move on after receiving an answer, not even aware of voting/accepting. Pragmatism rules, I can't blame them (although I don't like it either).

Comment: A special case is unclear questions, where the OP is asked for clarification through comments but does not respond. That's often a certain way to get the question down-voted. Personally I wait some 24 hours before casting such down votes, but other users are far more trigger-happy.

Comment: "Should they be reminded to check it?" - how though? We're talking about people here who essentially don't look unless it is in their own benefit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Absolutely nothing at all. You're helping everyone, not just the one person that asked the question. All those upvotes should be reward enough if you answered correctly and explained your answer.